# Simple scrollto not working

Tags: android, scroll, horizontalscrollview

Hi i have a simple program which contain a simple scroll view like android default calculator.
When user scroll more than offset value i want to scroll that to complete right or left.
But that's not working.
When i use myh.scrollBy(max, 0); nothing really changes.

Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int pos=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final HorizontalScrollView myh= (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myhview);
    myh.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            int xpos= myh.getScrollX();
            int max=640;
            if((xpos>50  && pos==0) || (pos==640 && xpos>590)){
                pos=640;
                myh.scrollBy(max, 0);
                }
            if((xpos<590 && pos==640) || ( pos==0 && xpos<50) ){
                pos=0;
                myh.scrollBy(0, 0);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

And xml is

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/myhview"

     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a01_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a00_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/a02_text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe you have a different default calculator, but mine doesn't have a ScrollView. It has what looks like a ViewPager, and that would be much easier if you're trying to swipe through different views like I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following whenever you want to scroll to the left or right:

```
horizontalScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        horizontalScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT); //Can also be FOCUS_LEFT
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you you'r offer works.but not my project work as i desired.do you have any suggestion about what i'm doing.

Comment: @ggmax I'm not sure what you mean that it is now not working as desired or what exactly you are trying to do. You had asked to scroll all the way to the left/right and that is what this answer solves. You could ask another question that is based on this new problem if you cannot figure it out.

Comment: @ggmax You're welcome. Don't forget if this answer was helpful you can click the check mark next to it to mark it as such.

Comment: sorry i can't do that because i need 15 reputation to mark up.